# Worth investing knowledge in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm a newbie in Sharepoint and need some help.

Is worth investing knowledge in Sharepoint from today and one year forward when there's a new version will be available in the market?

Comment: In a word: yes. I'll let the others give reasons why. There's a multi-million dollar conference happening right now, sharing knowledge on SharePoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. First, we are still a ways out to the new version. Also, the transition to the new platform will not happen immediately when the new version is launched. It will take about a year or more for people to migrate to the next version. Case and point: A lot of companies are just staring their migration to 2010. There will be plenty of opportunities with the previous (current) version. Secondly, as others have echoed, a lot of internals remain the same. What you learn today, will benefit you moving forward.

I highly suspect that the next version will heavily leverage more of a client side development model in which you see less back end ASP.Net forms development and more javascript and odata type of work. Microsoft already mentioned that the next version of share point will embrace HTML5.

Comment: I am hoping that they rewrite it (again) and switch to Asp.net MVC which would make it possible to have really rich Sharepoint front end and easier extensibility. Especially if they embrace html5.

Comment: I hear you. The current platform is showing it's age. A lot of the problems people are facing are due to legacy support. In a lot of ways I wish they could just rewrite it using more modern technology, but providing an upgrade path seems to be high on their list of priorities.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as a lot of the concepts that held true from the days of 2001 are still applicable.  Some things will change, new things will come aboard, but the core underlying things that make SharePoint are not likely to.  So yes, it is worthwhile investing into knowing SharePoint.

Comment: I would add that an attitude of investing in today's knowledge in any technology is worth 100 times more towards tomorrow's knowledge. Understanding how SP2010 runs today will help you only focus on what's new in SP2012.